# What is driver name of docker for mac?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

How do I create docker-machine from Command-Line?
I using `Docker for mac`(not Docker toolbox).

In Docker toolbox (this is not Docker for Mac), I could create docker-machine like `docker-machine create -d virtualbox default`

But now, I don't know default driver name of Docker for mac.

What is driver name?

Answer (score 1):

Are referring Docker for Mac beta? If so, then you don't have to create a docker-machine (VM). You can use Docker natively. Just open the terminal and execute any docker command.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

In this command `default` is the name of the virtualbox. If you open VirtualBox afterwards, you will see it created with the name "default"

If you wonder which driver is the default one, it is `virtualbox`.

Don't let the word `default` confuse you ;)