# How I can create docker-machine from Command-Line on Docker for Mac without VirtualBox?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I using docker for mac (not docker toolbox)
I know that I don't have to create docker-machine manually.

But I want to create Docker Machine from Command-Line without virtualbox.

I want to use xhyve based VM instead of VirtualBox on Docker.

Is there a way to create it from Command-Line?

#### Edit:

The following is output of `docker-machine --help` on my Mac

```
Usage: docker-machine [OPTIONS] COMMAND [arg...]

Create and manage machines running Docker.

Version: 0.8.0-rc1, build fffa6c9

Author:
  Docker Machine Contributors - <https://github.com/docker/machine>

Options:
  --debug, -D                       Enable debug mode
  --storage-path, -s "/Users/username/.docker/machine"  Configures storage path [$MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH]
  --tls-ca-cert                     CA to verify remotes against [$MACHINE_TLS_CA_CERT]
  --tls-ca-key                      Private key to generate certificates [$MACHINE_TLS_CA_KEY]
  --tls-client-cert                     Client cert to use for TLS [$MACHINE_TLS_CLIENT_CERT]
  --tls-client-key                  Private key used in client TLS auth [$MACHINE_TLS_CLIENT_KEY]
  --github-api-token                    Token to use for requests to the Github API [$MACHINE_GITHUB_API_TOKEN]
  --native-ssh                      Use the native (Go-based) SSH implementation. [$MACHINE_NATIVE_SSH]
  --bugsnag-api-token                   BugSnag API token for crash reporting [$MACHINE_BUGSNAG_API_TOKEN]
  --help, -h                        show help
  --version, -v                     print the version

Commands:
  active        Print which machine is active
  config        Print the connection config for machine
  create        Create a machine
  env           Display the commands to set up the environment for the Docker client
  inspect       Inspect information about a machine
  ip            Get the IP address of a machine
  kill          Kill a machine
  ls            List machines
  provision     Re-provision existing machines
  regenerate-certs  Regenerate TLS Certificates for a machine
  restart       Restart a machine
  rm            Remove a machine
  ssh           Log into or run a command on a machine with SSH.
  scp           Copy files between machines
  start         Start a machine
  status        Get the status of a machine
  stop          Stop a machine
  upgrade       Upgrade a machine to the latest version of Docker
  url           Get the URL of a machine
  version       Show the Docker Machine version or a machine docker version
  help          Shows a list of commands or help for one command

Run 'docker-machine COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is driver name of docker for mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039210/what-is-driver-name-of-docker-for-mac)

Comment: edit the question.

Comment: In your Mac did you install docker tool box or Docker for Mac beta? If you have installed Docker for Mac beta, then you don't have to install any VM.

Comment: @techtabu I have installed docker for mac. so I know I dont have to install VM, But I want to try to use `docker-machine create` command.

Comment: I don't think `docker-machine` command will be available if you installed Docker for Mac. I can't 100% verify it, since I have both installed in my Mac. Do you get any output for `docker-machine help`? Docker for Mac already use lightweight xhyve. However, check this [link](https://allysonjulian.com/posts/setting-up-docker-with-xhyve/), if this is what you are trying to do. [GIthub](https://github.com/zchee/docker-machine-driver-xhyve) for xhyve.

Comment: So, I think you have installed Docker tool box. In that case, you may be able to create VM using xhyve. Try out the links I have posted in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Docu(https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/) there are only a list of drivers:

- Amazon Web Services
- Microsoft Azure
- Digital Ocean
- Exoscale
- Google Compute Engine
- Generic
- Microsoft Hyper-V
- OpenStack
- Rackspace
- IBM Softlayer
- Oracle VirtualBox
- VMware vCloud Air
- VMware Fusion
- VMware vSphere

There is not a driver for xhyve

**EDIT**

I have found a docker-machine driver plugin for xhyve have a look at this project:

https://github.com/zchee/docker-machine-driver-xhyve